# Sails.js app debug within Webstorm takes way too much to start

Tags: node.js, sails.js, webstorm

I am developing a Sails using Webstorm IDE for debugging. I have noticed that while adding more and more controllers, models, features, etc the app's load time increases exponentially while in debug mode. If the normal app takes like 1-2 seconds to start, in debug mode sometimes it passes 2 minutes, which leads to 'The hook xxx takes too much to load' (xxx could be 'orm', 'request', 'logger', etc) errors and a big hassle overall in identifying problems via debug.

Anyone had similar problems with Sails and Webstorm? I am developing both on Windows and Ubuntu, node version 0.12, Sails version 0.11.

Comment: did anyone find the actual reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had the same problem on Mac using Node 12, Webstorm 10 and Sails 11. This happened immediately after installing Node 12. Project previously started in about 7 seconds but under Node 12 would not start due to hook timeout. If I extended the hook time for orm it simply timed out on the next hook, in my case view. Reverting to Node 10.38 cured the problem.

Comment: Did it really? I was having this problem on Node 10.25 before directly upgrading to 12. I will try on the Windows dev machine and confirm if it applies though.